Problema en C - Array de punteros a float
Tengo una duda con un ejercicio de la facultad que estoy tratando de hacer hace rato, y no puedo resolverlo.
El ejercicio dice así: "Escribe un programa en el que se defina un vector de 10 punteros a float, se lean diez números en las ubicaciones en las que
hacen referencia cada uno de los punteros del vector de punteros. Cuando esté completo, se sumen todos los números y se
almacene el resultado en una dirección a la que haga referencia un puntero ajeno al vector. El programa deberá mostrar el
contenido de todas las variables, tanto los punteros como los datos de tipo float."
Todavía no llegué a la parte en la que hay que sumar todos los números. Me quedé en rellenar el vector. Ya consigo llenar el vector (float * v[10]) con direcciones (declaro un puntero float * ptr y en una función con un for voy recorriendo el vector y haciendo v[i]=ptr+i). Eso anda, el problema es que las direcciones almacenadas en el vector y las direcciones de las posiciones del vector se terminan pisando en un momento, y ahí se rompe todo. Probé varias cosas pero ya no sé qué hacer. Otra cosa que quizás cabe mencionar es que dentro del mismo for donde le asigno los punteros al vector, voy haciendo
*(ptr+i)=num; (num es una variable flotante). Por ahora probé printeando con *v[i] y me lo guarda. Mi problema es que se pisen las direcciones de memoria.
Esto es memoria estática, así que el ejercicio no contempla nada de memoria dinámica en teoría.

No podemos ayudarte si no muestras el código
